# Mistakenly omitted information for a granted US visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, standard-visitor-visas

We applied for the visa application of my uncle as a group alongside our family application. The visa was granted successfully and he has traveled to US twice. Later on, while applying for a UK visa, we found a previous passport of my uncle for the years 2005-2010. My uncle claims he has a rejected Canada visa on that passport although there is no rejection stamp on it except the last page where it says "TRC ISBAD". I am not sure what that is for?

We didn't mention that passport details and rejection anywhere on the USA visa so my question is, shall we mention it in the application to UK visa now?

Comment: Visa rejection means his application was returned without prejudice due to a technical error. Visa refusal means it was evaluated and he was found ineligible for a visa. You should clarify which one applies here.

Comment: @JonathanReez Visa refusal.

Comment: What is your or was your uncle's situation then? What was he a citizen / resident of? TRC, I can think of two things but of them would be surprising: the Truth and Reconciliation Commission of Canada is abbreviated as TRC and Vietnam and Mexico has a Temporary Resident Card. I can't quite wrap my head around either how either is relevant here. We need a lot more details. Marking as unclear.

Comment: @chx He was never a citizen nor a resident. This was the first ever VISA he applied for back in 2010 somewhere. And He has nothing to do with Vietnam.

Comment: In general, we advice keeping the law but it's very much unclear whether there's any visa trouble here at all.

Comment: @chx what's the safe thing to do here?

Comment: @JonathanReez nice one with the terminology! More stuff like that!

Comment: The usa visa application never asks if you've had immigration problems in another country. Besides, your "lies" were not wilful and not material and would have had no effect on the outcome.

Comment: @greatone The lie was material even if not wilful. That is not in doubt at all. Having been previously refused a visa to another country is a material event when being evaluated for a visa to another country. US courts have already ruled on that issue.

Comment: @Sheik Paul of Osawatomie no they have not. It would only have been material if that information had led to the refusal of the OP's visa. The UK's courts may have a different opinion but they're soon going to be irrelevant.

Comment: @greatone  The BIA has held that a misrepresentation made in connection with an application for visa or other documents, or for entry into the United States, is material if either:
I. the alien is excludable on the true facts, or
2. the misrepresentation **tends to shut off a line of inquiry which is relevant to the alien's eligibility and which might well have resulted in proper determination that he be excluded**. A previous visa refusal is material.

Comment: @Sheik Paul of Osawatomie "nonimmigrant visa (NIV) applicant's misrepresenting the fact that the applicant was previously refused an NIV is not, in itself, a material misrepresentation" https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM030209.html and that is for the question about previous usa visa refusals. The ds160 doesn't even ask about Canadian refusals. Please stop misleading people.

Comment: @greatone The Department of State is not the lawmaking body of the USA. The BIA is a lawmaking body and barring an overrule by the Circuit or Supreme court, it's decision supersede the DOS. Let's get that very clear here.

Comment: @Sheik Paul of Osawatomie I don't think you have read the link. You're still trying to mislead without posting relevant citations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58593/discussion-between-sheik-paul-of-osawatomie-and-greatone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should be honest with the UK people **IF** indeed you confirm that he was previously denied by Canada. However when the time comes for renewing his US visa, he needs to maintain the old story he told them. Switching a narrative to immigration midstream can have [disastrous consequences](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/Print/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ.html).

Practically you want there to be consistency in your stories to different countries immigration databases because you do not want to trip up over lies. As it is said, the truth is one but lies metamorphose and keeping track of lies becomes problematic. At the same time immigration and consular officers and immigration law can be very rigid and unforgiving and people have been punished for coming clean on hitherto undisclosed transgressions.

We also need to straighten out some information. Yes the USA and UK and other [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) countries share information with regards to immigration. They however are not real time sharing **every detail** about every applicant for an immigration benefit among themselves. I know because I know several people who have conflicting information with different Five Eyes embassies and successfully get visas. Even within the same USA immigration system I know people with different answers to the same question on forms. Americans themselves will tell you [*if it ain't broke, don't fix it*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:If_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it). Note I am not **advocating** you deliberately set out to give false information.